# How to clear out/delete tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, garbage-collection, deep-learning

As I understand, `tf.reset_default_graph()` only creates a new graph and sets it equal to the default graph. So, the previously created tensors would just be lying around occupying the memory. I have also read the unreferenced tensors are not garbage collected (like normal variables in Python are).

If I am running a cross-validation to search for a set of hyperparameters and thus creating the same graph, again and again, how do I get rid of the previously created tensors?

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: This is related or duplicate [Tensorflow delete graph and free up resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58435961/1782792) @SantoshGupta7 There is a bit of a misconception in the question, in a setup like cross-validation the graph and tensors shouldn't usually take a lot of space, but the session (where variable values are stored and resources are pooled for training) might. Graphs become big when they are "frozen" (variables converted to constants) and/or when they have a _very_ large number of operations. In any case if you don't keep references to objects they should be garbage collected.

Comment: @jdehesa i dont think in tensorflow 1 the unreferenced tensors were grabage collected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem when designing experiments, after researching about this problem, the only solution that worked for me is [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36465#issuecomment-582749350). As you can read in that link, it seems to be a design flaw and the TF team doesn't seem to care about fixing.

The solution is to create a new process for each cross-validation iteration. So when the process finishes the system kills it and releases the resources automatically.

```
import multiprocessing

def evaluate(...):
    import tensorflow as tf
    # Your logic

for ... in cross_valiadtion_loop:
    process_eval = multiprocessing.Process(target=evaluate, args=(...))
    process_eval.start()
    process_eval.join()
```